# How to correct shading when connecting faces?

Tags: faces

On this image I selected four vertices and then I pressed F to create a face and I repeated until I connected the two parts of the object. Then I deleted the "internal faces". But the shading is still wrong. Recalculating the normal doesn't fix it. I deleted one of the faces and recreated it and the shading on it was correct.
What is causing this un-smooth shading and how can I correct it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add faces using <kbd>F</kbd> to a mesh they default to Flat shading - even if the rest of the object is set to Smooth shading. To set all faces to Smooth shading in *Object* mode, simply click 'Smooth' shading in the toolshelf (<kbd>T</kbd>). Alternatively, in *Edit* mode, simply select those faces, press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the Faces menu and select 'Shade Smooth' (or 'Shade Flat' to set individual faces back to Flat shading).

Comment: OMG! You are right! Thank you so much. I am pretty sure I quit Blender once just because of that as I am now recalling. I was expecting that shading is per scene/object. Why can an object have two shadings at the same time?